# Fix timecode in merged vobs

Tags: video, timecode

I use mpeg streamclip to fix the timecodes in merged vobs. I would like a command line utility that does this without having to recode if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Libav has the tool avconv, which allows you to do that with the video filter setpts=PTS-STARTPTS.

I haven't tried this, but the following should do the trick for you:

```
avconv -i in.vob -vf 'setpts=PTS-STARTPTS' -c:a copy -c:v copy out.vob
```

For more information you can check out http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/avconv.1.html

Comment: If a video filter is used, the stream *has* to be re-encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be guessing [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) or [ffmbc](http://code.google.com/p/ffmbc/)..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool I made to fix the timecode without re-encoding, https://sourceforge.net/projects/vob-timecode-fixer/

Comment: Can you please add some detail as to how this tool is used.  Right now, there isn't enough detail for someone to determine if the tool will be helpful to them (ie, within their ability to make use of it).  If you can briefly describe what the tool does and how to make use of it, that would be a great improvement to the answer.

Comment: It's by using FFMpeg to copy the video and audio stream and mux it into a new VOB File.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, although I more was pointing out that explanation of how a user would use the tool would greatly improve the answer.  Right now, it might not be clear to someone how to make use of the tool.

Comment: It's actually a pretty simple program (built as a compiled batch file). All you need to do is open the application, drag and drop the .vob file into it and press enter.
Then it will ask for an output filename, you just specify the filename (with or without the vob extension, doesn't matter ;-) ) and press enter again.
The fixed VOB will be saved to the users Documents folder.

I can't assure you it will work on all files, but sometime a simple remux should help and this is just a simple program to do just that.